# Making div's background merge with body background

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm trying to solve a problem without using js, but I don't know if it's possible.
I'm having a div in the middle of a page. I made it look invisible by making the div's and body's background merge using css.
The problem I have is that if I move the div, It's still practically invisible, because the background doesn't move with it. Using "background-position: fixed" screws up the merge.

Any ideas?

Here is my css, you can see the project [here](http://reality.royalwebhosting.net/three.php) (just open it and click anywhere).

```
    body{
        background: url(../img/forest.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .panel{
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        z-index: 2;

        background: url(../img/forest.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: inherit;
        -moz-background-size: inherit;
        -o-background-size: inherit;
        background-size: inherit;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .panel.hover{
        top:-400px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue with the method you are using I would suggest looking into the css:

```
background-position
```

property...

You can find the W3 page [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

However I would instead suggest to do the following:

Instead of trying to align the background of the smaller div with the outer div, just make the opacity of the div 0 by default, and set it to 1 on hover. You can use the opacity property as such:

```
opacity: 0;
```

this way you do not need to worry about trying to align the background of the smaller div with the larger div. You method may work OKAY for now, however later on if / when you try and make the background scalable (depending on the screen size of the user) you are going to run into problems!

Good luck!